# r shiny ggplot2 stacked bar chart based on selected column

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

In my shiny app, I would like to plot a stacked bar chart based on the metrics that I chose from a drop down menu.

I have 3 numeric column: customer number, transaction number, and amount_paid.

In the drop-down menu (metrics_type) I can choose anyone of these. My bar plot will change accordingly.

One way suggested online was to put all the metrics in one column and the filter the rows that belong to that metrics.

I try to keep the metrics separated. I select the factor columns and metrics columns and change the metrics column's name.

I keep getting the error message "Column `weight_metrics` must have a unique name". I don't know what's wrong.

I am new to shiny. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Regard,

Bing

============================

Here are the simplified codes:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

summary_1 <- read.csv("summary_1.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'var_type', label = NULL,
              choices = c("Gender", "Age Group"),
              selected = "Overall",
              width = '250px'),

  selectInput(inputId = 'metrics_type', label = NULL,
              choices = c("# Customer" = "numb_ctm", 
                          "# Transaction" = "numb_trn", 
                          "$ Cost" = "tot_amt_pd"),
              selected = "tot_amt_pd",
              width = '250px'),

  DT::dataTableOutput("monthly_sum"),
  plotOutput("monthly_comparison")
)

server <- function(input,output) {

  data1 <- reactive({
    temp <- summary_1 %>%
      select(din_month, category, input$metrics_type)

    colnames(temp)[-1] <- "weight_metrics"

    temp <- temp %>%
      filter(var_type = input$var_type)
  })

  output$monthly_sum <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(
      data1(),
      options = list(order = list(1, 'desc')),
      rownames = FALSE,
      colnames = c('Month', 'Group', 'metrics_type')
    )
  )

  output$monthly_comparison <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data1(), aes(din_month)) + 
      geom_bar(aes(weight = weight_metrics, fill = category))  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The data are here:

```
var_type,category,month,numb_ctm,numb_trn,tot_amt_pd
Age Group,G1: 24 to 37 year old,2018-01-01,896,1136,24701
Age Group,G2: 37 to 42 year old,2018-01-01,99,758,41972
Age Group,G2: 43 to 58 year old,2018-01-01,210,2180,44262
Age Group,G4: 59 to 74 year old,2018-01-01,1025,1408,198467
Age Group,G1: 24 to 37 year old,2018-02-01,27,1681,22071
Age Group,G2: 37 to 42 year old,2018-02-01,297,372,74920
Age Group,G2: 43 to 58 year old,2018-02-01,698,137,74063
Age Group,G4: 59 to 74 year old,2018-02-01,1172,2764,41573
Age Group,G1: 24 to 37 year old,2018-03-01,951,428,3584
Age Group,G2: 37 to 42 year old,2018-03-01,734,896,66483
Age Group,G2: 43 to 58 year old,2018-03-01,185,1129,24417
Age Group,G4: 59 to 74 year old,2018-03-01,1501,847,48692
Age Group,G1: 24 to 37 year old,2018-04-01,275,228,55665
Age Group,G2: 37 to 42 year old,2018-04-01,510,1374,33090
Age Group,G2: 43 to 58 year old,2018-04-01,781,986,122279
Age Group,G4: 59 to 74 year old,2018-04-01,0,1396,49184
Age Group,G1: 24 to 37 year old,2018-05-01,240,1438,46586
Age Group,G2: 37 to 42 year old,2018-05-01,504,381,46717
Age Group,G2: 43 to 58 year old,2018-05-01,358,813,132963
Age Group,G4: 59 to 74 year old,2018-05-01,659,1450,32746
Age Group,G1: 24 to 37 year old,2018-06-01,124,1321,3734
Age Group,G2: 37 to 42 year old,2018-06-01,619,30,15391
Age Group,G2: 43 to 58 year old,2018-06-01,195,1265,50682
Age Group,G4: 59 to 74 year old,2018-06-01,489,1987,132992
Gender,F,2018-01-01,2045,5043,151696
Gender,M,2018-01-01,497,2793,50950
Gender,F,2018-02-01,974,205,184919
Gender,M,2018-02-01,2177,3949,159286
Gender,F,2018-03-01,43,46,9828
Gender,M,2018-03-01,927,520,40851
Gender,F,2018-04-01,288,4875,51426
Gender,M,2018-04-01,778,1994,74220
Gender,F,2018-05-01,1915,4693,258544
Gender,M,2018-05-01,1736,3550,17810
Gender,F,2018-06-01,346,4311,103181
Gender,M,2018-06-01,1157,907,83196
```

Comment: You do not have variable var_type  in your temp dataframe. The error is here: filter(var_type = input$var_type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my mistake:

I change the column name using `colnames(temp)[-1] <- "weight_metrics"`

This line actually changes all the columns except the last one's name to `weight_metrics`. :-(

I changed it to

`names(temp)[length(names(temp))]<-"weight_metrics"`

Now the code works.